# How to use CMake to build multiple platforms from one master CMake project without cache problems

Tags: caching, cmake, multiplatform

I have two projects called `A` and `B` that have complete working CMakeLists.txt projects, and each project can be built completely without errors.  I would like to have a `master` project defined in CMake that will build both `A` and `B` (and maybe a hundred other things eventually).

My top level `CMakeLists.txt` project looks like

```
add_subdirectory(A build-A)
add_subdirectory(B build-B)
```

and CMake can parse all the files and make can start building just fine.

The problem is that project `A` is for one architecture (`x86_64`) and `B` is for a different architecture (`k1om`) and when CMake invokes various features like

```
 find_package(Boost ....)
```

it caches the results of the library paths for the first architecture and reuses them (incorrectly!) for all subsequent architectures.  We have Boost compiled for both `x86_64` and `k1om`.

Is there a way to have CMake do what I want to do, by entirely invalidating the cache between the two projects? Something like this would be ok:

```
add_subdirectory(A build-A)
cmake_invalidate_cache_and_forget_everthing_that_just_happened()
add_subdirectory(B build-B)
cmake_invalidate_cache_and_forget_everthing_that_just_happened()
...
```

I am fully aware that I can just make a shell script that does this and just runs `cmake` multiple times in different output directories, but it would be really nice to have a uniform "entry" point for all projects written in CMake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend using a "super-build" setup whereby each subproject is included via [`ExternalProject_Add`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/module/ExternalProject.html) rather than `add_subdirectory`.  This gives very clean separation between the subprojects' builds.  I think you'd be fighting CMake very hard by trying to tinker with the generated CMakeCache.txt!

However, I've never tried actually doing this where the architecture differs between subprojects.  So all I can do is suggest you try it  - I think it should work.

([This article](http://www.kitware.com/media/html/BuildingExternalProjectsWithCMake2.8.html) may help).

Answer (score 1):

I think using ExternalProject, as Fraser suggests is the best practice for your setup, but I don't think it's going to solve the issue your having. Correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds like you're using the same build tree for both platforms. Is that correct? If so, I can't see what can be gained from that.

If I'm wrong and you're just trying to prevent certain projects from configuring on certain architectures, then you should look into CMake's architecture blocks, like if(WIN32) ... if (CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P 8) ... there are many other ways to limit code exposure base on compiler, 32 vs 64 Windows, *nix, MAC, etc ...

If I'm still not understanding, then my apologies, perhaps you can attempt a clear explanation. Perhaps all you need it the unset command for your cache variables that are incorrectly set in cache because of a different architecture. See: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/unset.html

If that's the case though, you really should reconsider the design of your project because that approach sounds like an unmaintainable mess. Sorry.

Comment: I don't want to use `unset` as that is a management nightmare. You are correct, that the build tree between the two platforms has a big overlap (there are several layers of add_subdirectory(), include(), etc.)

Comment: There really isn't a good way to share the build trees among architectures. Can I ask why you would even want to do that? It's not like you can share the libraries built on Windows with Linux, so you're not saving any build time or disk space. What is the advantage? Certainly it's not simplicity.

Comment: This is a very special case. We are using Intel Phi coprocessors. The coprocessors have their own architecture - not x86.  However, everything "runs" on the same system, there is a component that runs on the Xeon host CPU and a component that runs on the coprocessor. It is really one application with two processes that communicate at high speed over the motherboard PCIe bus.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work with `ExternalProject_Add` (Thank You [Fraser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29111609/364818)). Here is what it looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(Demo1)
include(ExternalProject)

ExternalProject_Add(
  A-build 
  SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/A
  INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)

ExternalProject_Add( 
  B-build   
  SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/B
  INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)
```