# CMake errors in target creation

Tags: windows, cmake

I am using cmake-3.4.0 on Windows.
I have basic understanding of cmake.
I have trying to build two target executables in a folder called `util\`.
I intend to cross compile two source files `util\celtenc.c` and `util\celtdec.c`, and link the two object files created (celtenc.c.obj and celtdec.c.obj) 
against static lib: `libcelt-0.0.0-sb-None-hexagon.a`
and create two targets `celt_Enc` and `celt_Dec`.

Below is my `util\CMakeLists.txt`. I tried different things but it fails to build the two targets.

Case 1] When I disable the line `SET( CMAKE_C_FLAGS  "" CACHE INTERNAL "")`
It takes my `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` set in a top level CMakeLists.txt and gives error:     `linker option neglected` and no executable is built, although the corresponding two *.c.obj files are built.

Case 2] So to disable/unset my previous `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` I add a statement as below:

```
SET( CMAKE_C_FLAGS  "" CACHE INTERNAL "")
```

then it complains and gives error about invalid `namespec -l libcelt-0.0.0-sb-None-hexagon.a`

What am I missing? How can I modify this CMakeLists.txt to compile the above two source *.c files and link them to obtain the two executable targets?

```
if ("${TARGET_ARCH}" MATCHES "hexagon") 

     add_executable ( celt_Enc celtenc.c  )
     target_link_libraries(celt_Enc libcelt-0.0.0-sb-None-hexagon.a  )

     add_executable ( celt_Dec celtdec.c )
     target_link_libraries(celt_Dec libcelt-0.0.0-sb-None-hexagon.a   )  
     SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES( celt_Dec  PROPERTIES CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-v  -L ..\ -llibcelt-0.0.0-sb-None-hexagon.a -lhexagon")

    SET( CMAKE_C_FLAGS  "" CACHE INTERNAL "")

    #SET( CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "-mv66 -O3 -v " CACHE INTERNAL "")

else()
    message( STATUS "Setting Non-Hexagon target link libraries." )
    target_link_libraries ( celt_Enc ${CELT_SHARED_LIB_NAME} )
endif()                                                                                                          

if(WIN32)
  set_target_properties( celt_Enc PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "/INCREMENTAL:NO" )
  set_target_properties( celt_Dec PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "/INCREMENTAL:NO" )
endif()
```

Comment: Why are you linking the `.a` library twice? It is already linked in `target_link_libraries()` so there shouldn't be a need to set `-L ..\ -llibcelt-0.0.0-sb-None-hexagon.a` again in the `set_target_properties()` call. You can actually do everything in one call `target_link_libraries(celt_Dec /path/to/libs/libcelt-0.0.0-sb-None-hexagon.a hexagon)`.

Comment: What **actually** do you want to achieve by playing this dirty game with `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` variable? If you want to build binaries for **different platforms** in the single CMake project, then it is not what CMake is intended for. See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29111252/how-to-use-cmake-to-build-multiple-platforms-from-one-master-cmake-project-witho) for possible approaches. If you want to adjust compiler settings for the target platform, then `CMakeLists.txt` is not a right place for that. This should be done in the **toolchain** instead.